# What is the meaning of this solution

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following equality:

$$ \sin (t + \pi) = \sin (t)$$

$$ t + 0.5\pi = t + k2\pi  \space \text{or} \space t + 0.5\pi = \pi - t + k2\pi $$

Let's say you want to find the solutions on $[0, 2 \pi]$, what does the left expression mean:

$$ k2\pi = 0.5 \pi$$

What does this mean mathematically? Does it contribute to the solution set at all?

Comment: Or just $ \sin (t + \pi) = - \sin(t) $ ? I don't get the question quite well, tbh.

Comment: The first equality is an equation. Since $\sin(t+\pi)=-\sin t$, the equation $\sin(t+\pi)=\sin t$ is equivalent to $-\sin t=\sin t$, i.e $\sin t=0$, whose solution is $t=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If this is from a book, presumably there were some words before (and possibly between) the two lines of equations that are supposed to explain why one would write these equations. What reasons were given?

Comment: @DavidK If was just an example. You have a certain domain, and you want the solutions, so you fill in integers for k. However, I don't understand what the expression on the left would mean and if it would contribute to the solution set.

Comment: This particular example doesn't make much sense. It's a little hard to explain how the $k2\pi$ term works when it seems it does _not_ work in this particular example.

Answer (score 0):

I will ignore the specific equations given in the question, because it seems the point is to understand why the term $k2\pi$ (or $n2\pi$ or $2n\pi$ or other variations) sometimes appears in an equation in the solution of a math problem.

Here is a simple example: find all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \sin(t) = -\frac{1}{2}. $$

Now, we know $\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{6} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin(-t) = -sin(t)$,
so $t = -\frac{\pi}{6}$ is one obvious solution to this equation.  But that is not the only value of $t$ that solves the equation. You could also set 
$t = -\frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi$,
or $t = -\frac{\pi}{6} + 4\pi$,
or $t = -\frac{\pi}{6} - 2\pi$,
or $t = -\frac{\pi}{6} - 34\pi$.

In fact there are many possible solutions.
What do they all have in common?
Every one can be written in the form
$$t = -\frac{\pi}{6} + k2\pi \ \mbox{where  $k$ is an integer.}$$

This is especially good to know in case there are some other conditions that $t$ must satisfy.  For example, if you want $t \in [0, 2\pi)$, not just any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, 
then clearly the "solution" $-\frac{\pi}{6}$ is not acceptable.
But $-\frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi \in [0, 2\pi)$,
so that solution *is* acceptable.  The term $k2\pi$ lets us add or subtract 
$2\pi$ as many times as it takes to reach a value that satisfies all our conditions,
if there is any such value.